# Unknown Module Error in Verilog, but module exists already

Tags: verilog, hdl, vivado

I'm doing a prelab for a digital logic class I'm in. We had to design an n-bit counter and a half adder, and then another module where you use the nbitcounter and the half adder together.

I'm having problems instantiating the counter in my new module. It says that `nbitcounter` doesn't exist, but I'm looking at it in my list of design files and I've already run a test on it, so I know it works. Could anyone help me get to the bottom of this?

```
module nBitCounter
    #(parameter N=4)
    (input wire clr ,
     input wire clk ,
     output reg [N-1:0] q
    );
    
 always @(posedge clk or posedge clr)
 begin
    if (clr == 1)
        q <= 0;
    else
        q <= q + 1;
  end
endmodule
```

```
module counter2adder(clk, clr, s, c_out);
//Port and wire declarations:
    input wire clk, clr;
    output wire s, c_out;
    wire [2:0] out;
 //Logic:
    nBitCounter #(.N(2)) 2count(
    .clk(clk),
    .clr(clr),
    .q(out)
    );   
    
endmodule
```

As you can see, `counter2adder` isn't finished, but I stopped because I saw this error. Another thing. The file for the counter is called `n-bitCounter.v`.  I don't know if that changes things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I compile your 2 modules, I get a compile error on the instance name.  Change:

```
nBitCounter #(.N(2)) 2count(
```

to:

```
nBitCounter #(.N(2)) count2 (
```

Instance names, like all identifiers in Verilog, must not begin with a number (`2count`).

I also get a warning on the bit width of `out`.  Change it to:

```
wire [1:0] out;
```

---

It is a common practice to name the file the same as the module.  The `nBitCounter` module should be in a file named `nBitCounter.v`, for example.

If you still have problems compiling the 2 modules, just add them both to the same file until you can get help from your instructor on Vivado tool usage.